# i using solang, why frontend get value require send a transaction?

Tags: solang, frontend

https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/counter/solang

hi there, i use this example, all good until i try to get value in frontend, it need send a transaction to get count value, why?

This is how I get the value, following the test code in the example:

```
    const val = await program.methods
      .get()
      .accounts({ dataAccount: dataAccount.publicKey })
      .view()
```

I remember that there is no need to spend gas fee to get value in Ethereum...